# get current location region from local system

Tags: go

I need to get the Country/City (eg: `America/New_York`) from my local system to give to an api using the LoadLocation(value string) in the time package.

How can I get this without using any external configuration to get the region?

Comment: What  type of client? UDP, TCP, HTTP, FTP, carrier pigeon? You seem to know the `location` so just send that one, e.g. via a custom HTTP header. This has _nothing_ to do with time.LoadLocation.

Comment: I want to get the location from my machine to send it to the server. I may run this in different machines, so I need a way to get the location from any machine. Is this clear enough? @Volker

Comment: Okay, so please edit your question. The server part is totally irrelevant and distracting (as well as the send to server) and this is much less a Go question than a general software/system question. The question is: How to find the timezone name set on my machine?

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question now clearly asks how to get the timezone name.

Answer (score 1):

The IANA name of the location is not something that is guaranteed to be set properly on your system.

To get it, first check the `TZ` environment variable. If it is present, it **might** be a valid IANA name (eg: `America/New_York`).

If `TZ` is not set, look at what `/etc/localtime` points to (it is usually a symlink). In most cases, it will point to something like `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York`. You would need to extract the area/location components yourself.

**Important note**: there are a lots of caveats here:

- the content of TZ, or the file pointed to by `/etc/localtime` could be the time zone abbreviated name. eg: `EST`. There is no way to go from that to a IANA name.
- TZ could be set but empty, meaning `UTC`
- `/etc/localtime` could be a copy of the actual tzdata file, which only contains time offsets, not the IANA name.

In short, it would be much better for everyone involved if the server accepted an abbreviated time zone name or a time offset.

Comment: If i send only the offset,  how can I handle daylight savings on the server side? This is my main issue. Is there any way to overcome this? My server runs a schedule so I need daylight savings to be handled as well.

Comment: You could try to detect the full name using the method above (unless someone has manually poked at their `/etc/localtime` file, it should be correct). But if you need to be sure, you may want to ask whoever is running the client to confirm the timezone name.