# Get system timezone name in tz database format

Tags: go, timezone

I want to get a system's timezone information in tz database format, e.g. "America/New_York". Also I want it to be platform independent, e.g. code should work on Windows, Linux and MacOS.

Tried two recipes:

```
viaLocation := time.Now().Location().String() // Gives "Local"
viaZone, _ := time.Now().Zone() // Gives "EST"
```

"EST" is somewhat better, is there any way to map it into "America/New_York"?

I don't mind migrating to Go 1.15 and import `time/tzdata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this reliably.

On Linux the local time is typically configured via /etc/localtime. The [file format](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tzfile.5.html) doesn't include the IANA name.

But even if it did, that's not the only way to configure the time zone. An obvious alternative is the TZ environment variable. I can set TZ to, say, UTC+4, so my local time zone doesn't have a name at all. This is a trivial example, but [the TZ value can be much more complicated too](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html).

The time/tzdata package is only used if the system doesn't provide time zone definitions, so importing that package doesn't help either.

[Marc's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63805394) shows how you can take a *guess* on Linux (and possibly MacOS), but it's nothing more than that.

So you see, it can't be done reliably on Linux at least. I assume MacOS works similar. I don't know how local time works on Windows, but I'm sure it's possible to configure a fixed UTC offset too, i.e. a nameless time zone.

Comment: Actually, there are solutions for this on Linux, but it depends on distro.  For example, in Ubuntu you can simply `cat /etc/timezone`.  To answer your question about Windows, one can use `tzutil /g` to get the Windows time zone ID, but you'd have to map it back to an IANA time zone ID using [CLDR data](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) or one of the many libraries that use it.

Comment: Actually, there is one way to get the local time zone on Windows, already mapped to an IANA zone for you - via PowerShell.  I added an answer for that here: https://superuser.com/q/1584967/217834